# I've converted my EOS to REX, do I need to stake it to earn interest or just let it be?

Tags: stake, rex

I've converted my EOS to REX and what else do I need to do to earn interest on REX? Do I get interest in EOS or REX and how do I withdraw this interest? Is the dividend daily or every minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have buy REX token you just have to wait for the rex token price to goes up in the market with this formula

REX price = (Total Lent + Total Unlent) / Total REX

To withdraw the dividend you would have to calculate and sell just the amount of the REX price that has been added to your REX total

I think the extra REX is calculated live, so you get your gains every seconds

I got my info from this link and this is the best guide I have find:

https://medium.com/eos-new-york/the-ultimate-guide-to-rex-participation-on-eos-9cc0e449b320

Great picture of the whole system:

https://i.redd.it/bv5o2svq0fw21.png

Comment: Do I need to stake my REX?

Comment: You cant stake your REX since lend them, but you can save them which give you the same security as stacking them